Optimizing calls to derived-class virtual methods from inside of a base-class implementation
Suppose I have an abstract class and derived class like so:
class base {
public:
    virtual void pure_func() = 0;
    // arbitrary method that makes call(s) to virtual method(s)
    virtual void virt_func() {
        pure_func();
    }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    // final method
    void pure_func() final {
        // ... do something ...
    }
};

I am wondering if there is a way to inherit the implementation of virt_func such that the call to pure_func is made without dynamic dispatch (if virt_func is called through a derived class pointer of a type that finalizes the pure_func method).
I am aware that a common compiler optimization is to skip a vtable lookup if the type is known statically, but since this implementation is written once in the base class I believe this necessitates a virtual call. I am more or less asking if there is a way to reimplement abstract base class methods for each derived class, such that an optimizing compiler can better handle calls to methods defined as virtual in the base class and implemented in the derived class (e.g., skip vtable lookups if method is final, etc.). I have never heard of an optimization that does this.
Things I have thought of but have decided against for various reasons:

writing a macro with the "standard" definitions (readability concerns + prevents use of protected/private base members);
copy-paste implementations into each derived class instead (maintainability + prevents use of protected/private base members)
writing an "implementation class" that I extend from instead (just pushes the problem by one step);
static polymorphism/static dispatch (AFAIK this precludes runtime polymorphic benefits, since none of the derived types would have a common base type).
composition (write a shared separate type specifically with the implementations)---my intuition says that this could work but similar issues to the macro and static polymorphism cases might arise.

I am asking this mostly for educational purposes. However, the problem came up as I was writing some hot code for a base buffer class that uses functions that follow this pattern, so I would like to avoid unnecessary virtual calls where possible. Something to note is that in my specific case all of the implemented functions in the base class are relatively small, just numerous.

Apologies if this is something that has already been asked, as you might be able to tell from the title I am not exactly sure how to word this in a searchable way.

If the types are known statically and the compiler can see all of the relevant implementations it can de-virtualize the calls without you needing to do anything.  For instance, note that in main the compiler has emitted a static call derived::pure_func() instruction in this example.

"if there is a way to inherit the implementation of virt_func such that the call to pure_func is non-virtual" - C++ is complete in the sense that you can build whatever you'd like.  What I'm mostly surprised about that the considerations you've made are a-typical C++ solutions. 3-5 starts to look C++-ish.
Anyway, to get anywhere here, stay away from opionion-based territory. Ask specific questions.

@MilesBudnek thanks, that's really interesting to see! Is it perhaps due to inlining though? What I mean is if the compiler didn't choose to inline it seems like we would still end up with the vtable lookup inside of the virt_func implementation. (Which interestingly gcc seems to have partially inlined in virt_func itself.)

Why is virt_func() virtual? Hard to see the point of micro-optimizing any of this.

Despite my point about searchability, I managed to find the following StackOverflow Q&A shortly after asking this . I modified the code slightly for assembler brevity and to address the concerns I pointed out in my question. In the end, the solution was actually a combination of ideas 3 and 4 from my question:
struct base {
    virtual int once() = 0;
    virtual int shared() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct master : base {
    virtual int shared() override {
        auto ptr = static_cast<T*>(this);
        return ptr->once();
    }
};

struct derived1 final : public master<derived1> {
    int once() final { return 1; }
};

struct derived2 final : public master<derived2> {
    int once() final { return 2; }
};

Here is the link to the Compiler Explorer output. In the linked code I use noinline directives for illustrative purposes regarding direct function calls as opposed to vtable lookups since clang inlines most of the function calls otherwise.
The assembly output shows that (at least with clang), the derived class methods get called directly with static dispatch inside of the respective master<derived1>::shared() and master<derived2>::shared() methods.
This addresses the following pain points:

it allows for runtime polymorphism with the shared base class,
it uses templates to allow "shared" implementations that can also be optimized on the derived type.


Textbook example of why not to do this. Youu’ve taken something very simple and made it incomprehensible, all for the sake of removing one indirection, which you could have removed in the original by making virt_func() non-virtual, or indeed removing it altogether.

@user207421 "I am asking this mostly for educational purposes." The example is very clearly contrived and intended to be minimal to represent a general case. I was asking simply if it was possible. Making virt_func non-virtual obviously doesn't prevent the dynamic dispatch upon calling pure_func, which was my question ("inherit the implementation of virt_func such that the call to pure_func is non-virtual"). Maybe reread instead of typing righteous indignation lol.

And I am commenting for educational purposes.

You make it harder to see the connection between this answer and the question by renaming the functions. It seems like we might as well re-direct future viewers to the answer you copied from.
